# How to prove that $H$ is equal to $G$ when $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and they have the same order?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I find it obvious that each element of $H$ belongs to $G$ because $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ but how can I prove that each element of $G$ also belongs to $H$? I found it confusing to use the condition '$G$ and $H$ have the same order'. Many thanks if you can help me.

Comment: What if $G$ has an element that $H$ doesn't have? It seems to me that $G$ would then be larger...

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1306288/group-order-calculation

Comment: @Prototank Can G be larger even when G and H have the same order?

Comment: Finite groups only.

Comment: @JamieCarr What does order mean?

Answer (score 3):

This is true in finite groups and follows from basic set theory. If $G$ is infinite then the situation is different. Take $G=\mathbb{Z}$ and $H=2\mathbb{Z}$. They have the same order, but are certainly not equal.

Comment: If you want a pair that isn't even shaped the same, $\mathbb Z^2$ has subgroup $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Yes also a cool example!!